# Formatting a string for a listbox in C#

Tags: c#, listbox, string-formatting

I'll start off by saying that the listbox is a requirement for a class project. I'm just trying to spiff it up and make it look nicer by formatting a string before adding it to a list box. I have an override for `Product.ToString()` that formats the string, but when I add it to the list box, the formatting dissapears.

`ToString` method in `Product` class:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    string newFormat = string.Format("{0,0}{1,20}", Name, Price);
    return newFormat;
}
```

Update method:

```
protected void updateLists()
{
    availableProducts_LB.Items.Clear();
    foreach (Product p in customer.AvailableProducts)
        availableProducts_LB.Items.Add(p.ToString());

    shoppingCart_LB.Items.Clear();
    foreach (Product p in customer.shoppingCartList)
        shoppingCart_LB.Items.Add(p.ToString());
}
```

Comment: when you place a breakpoint on return newFormat;  What is the value for newFormat

Comment: Specify the output os string how it would look like.

Comment: FYI - you can just do `Items.Add(p)`, and the listbox will call `ToString()` for you.

Comment: There has to be more to this. What you've posted should work fine.

Comment: I have check that code. For me there is no problem in code.

Comment: If i place a breakpoint on return newFormat, the format returned is correct. Ex: product will return "object name (spacese here) object price" but in the list box it will show "objectname objectprice"

Answer (score 0):

Just add your Product instances directly to the ListBox (don't call ToString):

```
availableProducts_LB.Items.Clear();
foreach (Product p in customer.AvailableProducts)
    availableProducts_LB.Items.Add(p);
```

The ListBox will use the Product.ToString method to display the items in the list.

Then put a breakpoint on the return statement in ToString to make sure it is the value you are expecting.

Comment: Yes, that's better. But if calling `ToString()` isn't working, this won't work either.

Comment: Will that actually produce a different result than manually calling `ToString()`, though?

Comment: @Bobson: The result you *see* will not be different, but internally you can get the actual product items from the listbox when interacting with it, instead of a string *representing* the product.

Comment: The tostring is returning the correct format, however, the listbox does not show it with the format but rather the format without the added spaces.